# Debian Linux Update FFmpeg to 4.2+

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, debian

I'm trying to use `spotdl` with `FFmpeg` on Debian Linux. I've install `pip3` and the necessary installations in order to download `spotdl`. Now, however, when I try to run a request with `spotdl`, such as download a song or something, I get this message:

[image]

How do I update FFmpeg to version 4.2 or greater? I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Debian has](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ffmpeg) 4.3.3 in Bullseye (stable). If you only have 4.1, it sounds like you're on Buster (oldstable) or earlier. You should probably consider upgrading to Bullseye; if you can't / won't, you can try running FFmpeg and spotdl in a container (Docker, lxc, etc.) or VM.